# How to turn a 4-part into a 5-part chorale texture

Tags: composition

I wrote this 5 part texture this morning only to discover that all I had done was double the tenor line an octave higher. Is this how its done? I dont see how else I am to write this without other awkward leaps or doublings. The reason I did this was because I wanted a 4 voice chord and then I was going to elaborate the top line for a solo violin part.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

> I dont see how else I am to write this without other awkward leaps or doublings

If you compare five-voice choral writing to four-voice textures, you'll find that leaps are more common in the inner voices and indeed that doublings unusual in four-part writing (such as the third of the chord) are more common in five parts.  The rule against parallel octaves and fifths is typically observed, however.  (That said, techniques that would be little used in four-voice writing, if not frowned upon as hiding a parallel passage, are not uncommon, such as one voice descending by step while another alternates descending fourths with ascending seconds, e.g., G-F-E-D-C in one voice and G-D-E-B-C in another.)

> I wanted a 4 voice chord and then I was going to elaborate the top line for a solo violin part.

This is something you *will* find in the literature, however: a four-voice keyboard texture with a solo part that is the same as or closely similar to one of the voices in the accompaniment.  In the end, of course, it's a matter of taste as to whether this is what you want.  (A good way to avoid that, if you seek to avoid it, is to write the accompaniment with a three-part texture.)

Another common technique, both in large-scale choral writing and in pieces for a soloist with an accompaniment, is to alternate, so not everyone is playing or singing at the same time.  Look at some Brahms sonatas, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly ok to double a voice at the octave, particularly if it's the melody.  If you do it all the way through a piece it hardly counts as consecutive octaves.

My only comment would be that, if this is to be sung by actual voices, the melody line might predominate TOO much.  You have both tenors and sopranos in a powerful part of their range. The lower female voices may have trouble competing.

Comment: Thank you but could you add to your answer how it might be done with "correct" voice leading. I know it is ok to double the melody but what I want to know is how to write it with 5 distinct independent voices.